# Open source C# project to display raster images

Tags: c#, gdal

I am planning to build a sample C# application in which a tiff file will be selected and displayed. Using GDALAPI i would like to perform  hillshade, slope, color-relief related calculations on the displayed raster. are there any opensource projects already available for display of raster along with its info?

Regards,
Kishore

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: sorry, i was incomplete. Now I have edited my question :)

Comment: There is a dedicated site http://gis.stackexchange.com/ for GIS questions. You might get a better answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool included with GDAL that does what you're asking for: [`gdaldem`](http://www.gdal.org/gdaldem.html). (It's written in C++, not C#. If you download the GDAL source code, you'll find it under `gdal/apps/gdaldem.cpp`.)

Here are some examples of using it.

### Source Heightmap

This is just a greyscale PNG I found on Wikipedia:

[image: Heightmap]

### Hillshade

```
gdaldem hillshade heightmap.png hillshaded.tif
```

[image: Hillshaded]

### Color-relief

```
gdaldem color-relief heightmap.png ramp.txt relief.tif
```

[image: Color-relief]

using `ramp.txt`:

```
0    0   0   255
63   0   255 255
127  0   255   0
191  255 255   0
255  255   0   0
```

(You provide colors for different heights, and `gdaldem` will interpolate).

### Slope with color-relief

```
gdaldem slope heightmap.png sloped.tif
gdaldem color-relief sloped.tif slope-ramp.txt slope-relief.tif
```

[image: Slope with color-relief]

Here's `slope-ramp.txt`:

```
0   255 255 255
90  0   0   0
```

(This time, you provide colors for different angles).

You might also be interested in some of other software using GDAL listed in the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDAL#Software_that_uses_GDAL.2FOGR).